# Trouble using protocol buffers with node.js

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, axios

I've got a small practice app that uses node, express and protocol buffer on the server-side and in the browser I'm using axios, longJS, protocol buffer and bytebuffer. My problem isn't making the connection but the data is being lost somewhere during the process. Something is being sent from the server and something is being received from the cient however the data isn't arriving.

SERVER SIDE CODE:

```
    let messageFile = ProtoBuf.load(path.join(__dirname, publicFolderName, 'message.proto'))
    .then((root) => {
        Message = root.lookup('message.Message');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });

let messagesStore = [
    {text: 'hey', lang: 'english'},
    {text: 'ho', lang: 'french'},
    {text: "Let's go", lang: 'spanish'}
];

let app = express();

app.use(express.static(publicFolderName));

app.use((rq, rs, nx) => {
    if(!rq.is('application/octet-stream')) return nx();
    var data = [];
    rq.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data.push(chunk);
    });
    rq.on('end', () => {
        if(data.length <= 0) return nx();
        data = Buffer.concat(data);
        console.log('Received data', data);
        rq.raw = data;
        nx();
    })
});

app.get('/api/messages', (rq, rs, nx) => {
    var randNum = Math.round(Math.random()*2);
    console.log(randNum);
    var message = Message.create(messagesStore[randNum]);
    console.log("Encode and decode: ", Message.decode(Message.encode(message).finish()));
    console.log("Buffer being sent, ", Message.encode(message).finish());
    var buffer = Message.encode(message).finish();
    rs.send(buffer);
})
```

CLIENT-SIDE CODE:

```
let ProtoBuf = protobuf;
            let Message;

            let messageFile = ProtoBuf.load('./message.proto', (err, root) => {
                Message = root.lookup('message.Message');
                console.log("Built Message: ",Message);
                loadMessage();
            });

            let loadMessage = () => {
                axios.get('/api/messages', {responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log('Response from server: ', response);
                        let message = Message.decode(response.data);
                        console.log('Decoded Message ', message);
                        document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(message, null, 2)
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error while getting messages, ",error)
                })
            };
```

The response from the server is an empty object, no error.

Any suggestions why would be much appreciated.

Comment: can log `buffer` in your server before you send it ?

Comment: Yeah, the buffer gets logged. There seems to be nothing wrong when I encode and decode the message in the server.